# How to make Unbreakable tools in Minecraft 17w48a (1.13 minecraft snapshot)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've tried the below command but it doesn't work anymore?

```
/give (yourname) minecraft:diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {Unbreakable:1}
```

Is there still a way to get unbreakable tools in minecraft 17w48a?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, the nbt data is now part of the (item) argument. You have to write your command like this:

```
/give @s minecraft:(put weapon here){Unbreakable:1} 1
```

put in the weapon without ( and )

Comment: It is correct. For reference, here's the blog post: https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/minecraft-snapshot-17w45a

Comment: Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20180430123050/https://minecraft.net/en-us/article/minecraft-snapshot-17w45a

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this command in the 1.13 snapshots [17w48a or any other snapshot relating to 1.13] is to execute your command like this, with the NBT next to the item name, rather than after the damage.

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe{Unbreakable:1b} 1
```

If you want to hide the "Unbreakable" flag on the pickaxe when you hover your cursor over it in the inventory, simply do this

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe{Unbreakable:1b,HideFlags:4} 1
```

You can, if you want, replace @p with @s.

You can go here for more information: [Tutorials/Command NBT tags - Official Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_NBT_tags)

Answer (score 0):

In Minecraft 1.13 the `/give` command was changed.

The give command used to work like this

```
/give (players) (item) ((count)) ((data)) ((nbt))
```

However, the new syntax looks like this

```
/give (players) (item) ((count))
```

The simplest way to get an unbreaking item is to give yourself the item and then use the `/enchant` command.

The syntax for the enchant command looks like this:

```
/enchant (player) (enchantment ID) [level]
```

To find out more about the changed and new 1.13 commands you can look here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.13

Answer (score -1):

For 1.13+

```
/give <targets> <item>[<NBT tag>] [<count>]
```

For 1.8+

```
/give <targets> <item> [<count>] [<data>] [<NBT tag>]
```

For 1.7-

```
/give <targets> <item id> [<count>] [<data>] [<data tags>]
```

Comment: This is way too general and unclear. What are you trying to make clear? Can you expand on this? Does it add anything new to the other answers?